# What's the recommended way to create an HTML element and bind a listener to it using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

At the moment I achieve this using something like this:

```
var myElem = "<tr id='tr-1'><td>content</td></tr>";
$("#myTable").append(myElem);
$("#tr-1").click(function() {
  // blah blah
});
```

Traditionally, when I wasn't using jQuery, I used to do something like this:

```
var myElem = document.createElement(...);
var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
myTable.appendChild(myElem);
myElem.onclick = function() {
  // blah blah
}
```

The thing is, in the second approach I already have a reference to `myElem` and I don't have to scan the DOM (`$("#tr-1")`) to find it, like the jQuery approach, and hence it should be much faster especially in big pages. Isn't there a better jQuery-ish way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can shrink it down/speed it up a bit like this:

```
$("<tr id='tr-1'><td>content</td></tr>").click(function() {
 // blah blah
}).appendTo("#myTable");
```

This takes out the need to find the element, and also you're dealing with a document fragment until you actually call [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), making it much faster to do DOM operations.

There's also [`$(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) version since 1.4 that doesn't *quite* work for your example, but is even more terse in some situations that you may want to check out.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more what do you mean by "and also you're dealing with a document fragment"? Thanks.

Comment: @Bytecode - Sure! When you do [`$(html)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) you're creating a [document fragment](http://developer-stage.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DocumentFragment) that's much quicker to work with, you're not working with the DOM, but a tiny fragment containing nodes that's much quicker to operate on, get it like you want then you insert it into the full DOM/your page.  It's just a more efficient (usually) way of dealing with things...jQuery also caches the fragments based on the html string (up to 512 bytes), so you can re-use them, making node creation from an html string much faster.

Answer (score 1):

use live events.   now when you add the element to the dom the live event gets added to the new element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tr-1").live("click", function() { 
    // blah blah 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about live events. However my goal was to eliminate the `$("#tr-1")` scan.

Comment: Not sure what the benefit of using live() on an element which there is only ever going to be one of on a a page.  It seems a bit more useful for adding events to a class or tag group of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just "cast" myElem into a jQuery object?

```
$(myElem).click(function() { ... });
```